# Stripe reflect connected account customer payment_method to platform customer payment method

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-stripe

I have implemented connected accounts in Stripe. The customers are created on the platform and when they want to make a payment on a connected account, the customer and his payment method from the platform are cloned in the connected account.

Now, if at that moment (payment) the customer of the connected account adds a new bank card I would like that this new card is reflected/copied in the payment_method of the same customer on the platform. This in order that if the customer wants to make a payment on another connected account he can retrieve this new bank card.

Any idea how to do that?

I can imagine something like retrieving the payment method of the connected account and then copying it to the customer of the platform. But I don't know if it's possible...

For information, I use Flutter (with flutter_stripe plugin) and Firebase (nodejs) as backend.

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: What kind of Connected accounts are you using? (Standard/Express/Custom) Depending on your business type, you might prefer to use [destination charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) instead, this way all the payments happen, and your Customer and Payment Method objects live on your Platform account, and the Connected accounts only receive the payouts.

Comment: Hi Vanya, I use standard accounts

Comment: Stripe dev-help answered that it is impossible to clone customers payment method from a connected account customer to a platform customer. They recommend to use SetupIntent. I can collect card informations via a form but I don't have any idea on how to put that info into a platform customer payment method. The doc refers to specific SDK Payment Element that doesn't exist in Flutter. So it is a black box to me.

Comment: SetupIntent can help you collect a new Payment Method from the customer, but not to copy it from Connected account to the Platform.

Comment: stripe-flutter supports PaymentSheet, which is the mobile alternative of the Payment Element: https://docs.page/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/sheet